# Unknown indicator on dashboard: P67-y on dashboard Toyota Vitz (Yaris)

Tags: toyota, dashboard, indicators, vitz

I recently bought a Toyota Vitz 2008 model and I am the second owner. Somedays back, while I was driving on a highway, I saw an indicator at the right side of the dashboard in white color. It was p67-y.

Since it was a white colored one and I could not find much information on that, I sort of neglected it. But it does not go away.

Recently I got my car serviced and even after engine and automatic transmission oil changes, the indicator does not go away. My mechanic does not have an idea either.

Now, this is starting to concern me. I am bit scared since I am still waking up in this part of the world.

Kindly let me know what this issue is. Should I stop using the car until I get the issue resolved?

[image: Yaris dashboard]

Comment: Image of this indicator: http://upload.autolanka.com/upload/monthly_04_2011/post-47558-041976300%201302745411.jpg

Comment: This indicator is not listed in the owner's manual (http://www.toyota.com/owners/resources/owners-manuals/yaris/2008?garagePrefVehicle=0&garageModelName=Yaris&garageYearValue=2008&addToVehicleList=false), I doubt it's critical.

Comment: After this indicator turned up, I drove about 250 + km without any problem. I still do not see or feel anything different.

Comment: Typically, yellow means "there is something wrong but you can still drive the car for a while" and red means "stop driving now!". Considering that this indicator is neither yellow nor red, I don't think it is critical.

Comment: @juhist that is exactly what my local mechanic said to me. Since it is white, do not worry, drive on.. have a look later when you are free